# Macro Keys not Detected AutoHotkey

Tags: macros, windows-8, keyboard, autohotkey

I have just purchased the Steelseries apex gaming keyboard and rival mouse. Unfortunately, each of these products has different software for macros and keyboard lighting, both of which are mediocre at most.

Instead of having 2 processes running in the background and having to use 2 crappy programs to write my macros, I have decided to use AutoHotkey for my macros, some of which I plan on making quite complex. The mouse was no problem in AutoHotkeys, with the two side buttons using XButton1 and XButton2, however no matter what I do, I can't detect my keyboard macro keys (M1 to M12 and MX1 to MX10).

Using a keyboard hook doesn't detect any keys, and looking online I can't find how to reference these keys either. I'm not even sure windows sees them, as when I try to input them into the shortcut key field in a normal shortcut they do nothing. So my questions are:

What is the name for the macro keys on my keyboard in AutoHotkey?

Is there any way to work around this problem without having to use the Steelseries Engine?

If I can't access them normally, is there a way to reassign them without external software?

(Optional) Is there any way to adjust the lighting on the keyboard and mouse without the Steelseries software as well?

Btw I'm using Windows 8 and here are the links to the [mouse](http://steelseries.com/products/mice/steelseries-rival) and [keyboard](http://steelseries.com/products/keyboards/steelseries-apex-gaming-keyboard). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to remap those special keys to something else in the keyboard driver? Say, something complex like `(WIN+)SHIFT+ALT+CTRL+F4` you would never use anywhere else. You could then catch that sequence as a normal hotkey in your script.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name for special keys that are not listed in AutoHotkey documentation by following steps [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

**Some notes and explanations:**

You can use that script for step 1:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
Sleep, 99999999999999999999
```

When you run it, check if keyboard hook is active by:

press here:

[image]

then here:

[image]

and if active, you should see something like here:

[image]

In the step 6 the hex value column is here:

[image]

If that is not working for you, try **Alternate solutions** in the link that I provided before.

Comment: Ya mine don't show up when I try that at all. It just shows the F5 key. I ended up having to make the steelseries program make the macro keys  output CTRL+F1, CTRL+F2 etc. and use autohotkeys from there. Thanks anyways.