# Simulate input of a 3D Mouse in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use autohotkey to control a program, which relys on the input of a 3D-Mouse (3DConnexion SpaceNavigator). How can I simulate a axis in autohotkey?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 3DConnexion SpaceNavigator uses same axeses as joystick? So check joystic controls here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#Joystick

If it does not helps, you can try to get the name of the control with that guide: http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys (some explanations here: [Macro Keys not Detected AutoHotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921492/macro-keys-not-detected-autohotkey/24927828#24927828))

By the way please write your impressions about 3D-Mouse (3DConnexion SpaceNavigator) in comments.

Comment: I'm not using the 3D-mouse this much. It was delivered with a machine we use at work. I want to automate it, so we don't have to stay there, just pushing buttons. But it seems solid.

Comment: It seems it is not a joystick. I tried it with your first tip, but didn't find a joystick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the SDK and write your own intigration...seems to be the only option, unless you figure out a way to communicate with the device by watching the usb signal

Comment: Though you do not have reuptation to comments on question, it is not a good way to represent. Better wait until you have proper reputation to comment